# Power automate Get a certain part of the email body

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, power-platform

today I'm working on a project where I get a piece of text from an email body and save it in a SharePoint list, but the piece of text varies every email from 1 to infinite, the pieces of text contain website domains or ip addresses.

[This is the email we are receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiMTQ.png)

In the picture shown above you can see that the "message" part contains 9 dots, these vary every email from 1 to infinite.

these dots contain websites or ip addresses.

[Here is the flow I used for the email with 9 dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z4qo.png)

Shown above is the flow i used for the email with 9 dots, but as i mentioned before these vary every time.
in the flow im using right now im using an array to define the domainname rows, for example: site 1 = 49, site 2 = 51, site 3 = 53.
The flow above works but I'm trying to find a easier way where power Automate automatically chooses/picks the domain names/ips, and used these in the rest of the flow.

What I'm trying to accomplish here is that power automate automatically sees how many dots there are and use these to make the array and post it to SharePoint (with the domain name behind the text aswell).

I have been searching on forums for a long time and couldn't find anything.

If any extra info is needed please tell me!

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the body to text, this will change the `<li>` tags to `*`. After that you can split that output on `'* '`. In a Select action you can use that array and per item you can look for the newline character to find the domain name value.

Below is an example

1.From Field in the Select action

```
skip(split(outputs('Html_to_text')?['body'], '* '), 1)
```

2.Map field (switched to Text mode)

```
substring(item(), 0, indexOf(item(), decodeUriComponent('%0A')))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @expiscornovus, Thanks for your help, but i still doint quite understand what you mean, im a bit new to powerplatform so that might be why.

so you are saying with the skip function you can skip a part of the text and after that you can find the bulletpoints in the HTML to Text outcome?

i tried this above and it only seems to save '[]', (this is the start and the end of the HTML to Text). 

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might not have found any `* ` at all? Would be interesting to see what the outputs is of the Html to text action. Can you share a screenshot of that section of your flow run?

Comment: Here i have a screenshot of the output, it just shows normal text here